# What is the wage of a Flaming Fist officer?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms

What is a Flaming Fist officer's wage?

Do they count as skilled mercenaries who are paid 2gp per day?

Comment: As Korvin said, are you asking in relation to *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus* specifically? What time or time period are you asking about?

Comment: I can find 97 references to pay in my copy of Avernus, and have also searched for wage and can't find anything resembling an answer to this question so I am curious why the above question is important?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Time period is 5E setting: After 1485 DR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### They are even more expensive than average skilled mercenaries.

According to the AD&D 1st edition [*Forgotten Realms Campaign Set*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/16782/Forgotten-Realms-Campaign-Set-1e) (p. 61), set in the mid-1360s DR:

> The Fist is expensive even by mercenary standards, due to its numbers and due to the fact that NONE of its front-line troops are less than 5th level. This makes The Fist a *[sic]* incredible weapon on the battlefield, but only to be afforded by nations or the very, very wealthy (and very, very angry).

The cost to hire the Fist is a base rate of 10,000 per day plus a share of plunder. Since there are approximately 2,000 members, it cost **approximately 5gp per member per day** to hire the company. The chronologically later [*Gold & Glory*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/17556/FR15-Gold--Glory-2e) for AD&D 2e (p. 8-11), set in the early 1360s DR, updates their number to 1,600, but it still costs 10,000 gp per day to hire the entire army, or nearly **6gp per member per day**.

This figure includes the company's travel and maintenance costs, and we might assume the standard ranking members are paid less than the high-ranking officers. However, that's just the wage you personally would earn if you were a member. In terms of the cost to hire them, *Gold & Glory* states that hiring a subsection of them costs a proportionate amount; hiring 10% of the group would cost 1,000 gp, so the price-per-man would be the same. They would also expect to be paid in a share of plunder, as mentioned, which effectively increases the total cost.

A considerable amount of time has passed since then, but the group remains largely the same and monetary inflation appears to be non-existent. According to the D&D Next playtest adventure [*Murder in Baldur's Gate*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/160318/Murder-in-Baldurs-Gate-5e), p. 32 (1482 DR):

> Other than tripling in size to its current membership of nearly six thousand, the mercenary company has not changed much since its early years.

The stats in that module suggest that the lowest-ranking members are below the 4th-level; private and lieutenant ranks are level 1 and 3, respectively. This suggests that much of the current-era growth of the Fist has been recruiting lower-level mercenaries. *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*, p. 162 (under the section ["The Flaming Fist"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/bgdia/baldurs-gate-gazetteer#TheFlamingFist) in the Baldur's Gate Gazetteer), could be interpreted to support this:

> The Flaming Fist offers employment and a sense of belonging to any who can lift a sword and follow orders.

However, they're certainly at least trained mercenaries. *Descent into Avernus* p. 177, [Table B: Upper City Denizens](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/bgdia/baldurs-gate-gazetteer#TableBUpperCityDenizens), recommends the statblock of a Knight for the Fists' officers, and the Veteran for their soldiers. This suggests they're typically well-trained, not just some peasant militia. Page 207 notes that [soldiers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/bgdia/baldurs-gate-gazetteer#Soldier) must report for training once per tenday, suggesting that they are skilled. Page 195, [Table H: Outer City Denizens](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/bgdia/baldurs-gate-gazetteer#TableHOuterCityDenizens), notes that they also have Guards, which suggests at least that some lower-ranking members exist. *Tomb of Annihilation*, p. 199, ["Flaming Fist"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/random-encounters#FlamingFist), concurs with this; a patrol is led by an NPC with the stats of a Knight or Veteran with 2d6 Guards, an Acolyte, and one Scout.

#### Summary

Historically, all Flaming Fists were elite mercenaries, and hiring them would cost 5gp per person per day or more. In modern times they are more numerous and have recruited less exceptional individuals to fulfill their duty of guarding Baldur's Gate, but there are still many exceptional high-ranking officers, while even the lowest-ranking members undergo regular training and could be considered skilled mercenaries.